# Get custom data in item collection array

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, model

This is somewhat confusing.. I hope my explanation is clear.

As we all know magento converts a php object(*I don't know what it is exactly*) to an Array by using:

```
$item->getData();    // Where $item is an item from a product collection
```

The above code does covert the object to an Array, but I want to add my own custom fields to it.

So, I tried the following while preparing the collection

```
foreach($collection as $item){
    $item->setData('custom_field', $value);  // Also tried $item->setCustomField($value);
}
```

By doing the above, I can get the `custom_field` value by doing `$item->getCustomField()` or `$item->getData('custom_field');` but I can't see this `custom_field` key in array when I am doing

```
$item->getData();
```

#### For Example:

Let us say, If I do

```
echo $item->getData();
```

I can see the following array in dump:

```
array(4) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(3) "623"
  ["type_id"] => string(12) "configurable"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2012-07-30 22:14:09"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2014-01-04 02:02:08"
}
```

But I want to see the following Array:

```
array(5) {
  ["entity_id"] => string(3) "623"
  ["type_id"] => string(12) "configurable"
  ["created_at"] => string(19) "2012-07-30 22:14:09"
  ["updated_at"] => string(19) "2014-01-04 02:02:08"
  ["custom_field"] => string(5) "Hello"
}
```

Comment: Maybe if you gave us an idea of what you are trying to achieve here, if you set the data and then in the loop call getData then it will be returned.

Comment: Like David said, we're going to need a little more detail about what you're ultimately trying to do. Maybe you need to create a product attribute that will store the data you're trying to save?

Comment: @andyjv I want to have my `custom_field` value in `$item->getData()`. Anyway, I got the answer below. (_I just forgot to mark it_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to save your item , then you can use it :

```
       foreach($collection as $item){
            $item->setData('custom_field', $value);  // or $item->setCustomField($value);
            $item->save();
        }
var_dump($collection->getFirstItem()->getData()); // print first item
```

Comment: Thanks... Wouldn't that effect performance? because saving each item in the collection is I think doing db query for each item..

Comment: Yes, that's not good for performance . The best way is to add  your custom field in your product collection before with $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_field'); (depends on how your custom field is stored)

Comment: How to do that? also I tried `$item->save()`.. I still can't see my custom field..

Comment: `$item->save()` literally saves the item to the database, so if the fields aren't originally a part of the collection then it can't be saved because there is no spot in the database for it.

Comment: Not a good performing ans, looping can make page too much slow to load.